# Find Duplicate Records?

Tags: node.js, express

Find all transactions that have the same sourceAccount, targetAccount, category, amount,
and the time difference between each consecutive transaction is less than 1 minute.

**Data Set**

```
[
  {
    "id": 3,
    "sourceAccount": "A",
    "targetAccount": "B",
    "amount": 100,
    "category": "eating_out",
    "time": "2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 1,
    "sourceAccount": "A",
    "targetAccount": "B",
    "amount": 100,
    "category": "eating_out",
    "time": "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "sourceAccount": "A",
    "targetAccount": "C",
    "amount": 250,
    "category": "other",
    "time": "2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "sourceAccount": "A",
    "targetAccount": "B",
    "amount": 100,
    "category": "eating_out",
    "time": "2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "sourceAccount": "A",
    "targetAccount": "B",
    "amount": 100,
    "category": "eating_out",
    "time": "2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "sourceAccount": "A",
    "targetAccount": "C",
    "amount": 250,
    "category": "other",
    "time": "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"
  }
]
```

List of all the duplicate transaction groups (category), ordered by time ascending.

The groups (category) should be sorted in ascending order of the first transaction in the group.

**Expected Output**

```
[
  [
    {
      "id": 1,
      "sourceAccount": "A",
      "targetAccount": "B",
      "amount": 100,
      "category": "eating_out",
      "time": "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 2,
      "sourceAccount": "A",
      "targetAccount": "B",
      "amount": 100,
      "category": "eating_out",
      "time": "2018-03-02T10:33:50.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 3,
      "sourceAccount": "A",
      "targetAccount": "B",
      "amount": 100,
      "category": "eating_out",
      "time": "2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z"
    }
  ],
  [
    {
      "id": 5,
      "sourceAccount": "A",
      "targetAccount": "C",
      "amount": 250,
      "category": "other",
      "time": "2018-03-02T10:33:00.000Z"
    },
    {
      "id": 6,
      "sourceAccount": "A",
      "targetAccount": "C",
      "amount": 250,
      "category": "other",
      "time": "2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z"
    }
  ]
]
```

**Below is the code I tried**

```
let transactions = []
var clean = records.filter((arr, index, self) =>
  index === self.findIndex((t) => (t.sourceAccount === arr.sourceAccount && t.targetAccount === arr.targetAccount && t.category === arr.category && t.amount === arr.amount)))

if(clean.length > 1){
    // array contains duplicate elements.
    transactions.push(clean)
}

return transactions
```

**Output I get from the above code**

```
[
    [
        {
            "id": 3,
            "sourceAccount": "A",
            "targetAccount": "B",
            "amount": 100,
            "category": "eating_out",
            "time": "2018-03-02T10:34:30.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 6,
            "sourceAccount": "A",
            "targetAccount": "C",
            "amount": 250,
            "category": "other",
            "time": "2018-03-02T10:33:05.000Z"
        },
        {
            "id": 4,
            "sourceAccount": "Aw",
            "targetAccount": "D",
            "amount": 1002,
            "category": "eating_out2",
            "time": "2018-03-02T10:36:00.000Z"
        }
    ]
]
```

Try lot of different codes but unable to get the expected output from dataset.
Can someone help me to get the **Expected Output**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function findTransactions(input) {
    const checkTimeDiff = (time1, time2) => {
        const diff = Number(new Date(time1)) - Number(new Date(time2))
        return diff < 60 * 1000;
    }
    
    let result= []
    for (let i = 0; i < input.length; i++) {
        let next= []
        let found = false;
        for (let j = i + 1; j < input.length; j++) {
            if (input[j].sourceAccount === input[i].sourceAccount && 
                input[j].targetAccount === input[i].targetAccount && 
                checkTimeDiff(input[j].time, input[i].time) &&
                input[j].category === input[i].category &&
                input[j].amount === input[i].amount) {
                next.push(input[j]) 
                input.splice(j, 1)
                if (!found) {
                    next.push(input[i])
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }
        if (next.length > 0) result.push(next);
    }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: can u help me to add this part too. Same output. List of all the duplicate transaction groups (category), ordered by time ascending.

The groups (category) should be sorted in ascending order of the first transaction in the group.

Comment: Adding `next.sort((a, b) => a.time-b.time)` before the `if (next.length > 0`... line should do